# Why is an NSDate in a Core Data managed Object converted to NSTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an object with a property with a Date type defined in my xcdatamodeld object. Why has it generated the NSManagedObject class with a NSTimeInterval? And how do I set a NSDate on it and then get an NSDate back off it?

Comment: That's odd. They should be NSDate objects. What store type are you using?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I get this if I check the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" checkbox when I'm generating my files.

This is because NSTimeInterval is a double in disguise, whereas NSDate is a class that inherits from NSObject.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the reasoning makes no sense to me. Every class in Objective-C inherits from NSObject. The question is: why is a string attribute translated to an NSString object and a date attribute to an NSInterval when generating NSManagedObject subclass with "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" checkbox checked. I'll accept "gremlins working at Apple" for an answer, btw.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij Unlike numbers, dates and boolean values, strings can't be represented as a scalar property, so the checkbox doesn't affect string attribute translations. Same for binary data attributes.

Comment: How do I create a NSManagedObject subclass so that there is both an int and an NSDate?

Comment: @VictorPrograss You can manually edit the generated entities and just replace `NSTimerInterval` with `NSDate*`. Also add `retain` to the `@property` annotation

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing the generated properties because you would lose those edits if you ever re-generate your class.

Answer (score 15):

Edit: apparently the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` is for `NSDateFormatter` only. `NSDate` uses a different reference than `NSDateFormatter`, which as explained in the comments is in 2001.
Sorry for my ignorance.

If you have "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" selected when you generated the `NSManagedObject` subclasses for your entities, it will use scalar properties like int and float instead of `NSNumber`.  This includes NSDate;  It will turn `NSDate` into an `NSTimeInterval` which is just a double.  This `NSTimeInterval` is a time interval since the 1970 standard epoch used by Apple (if it's before 1970 it probably is negative).

It's pretty simple to convert the `NSTimeInterval` back into an `NSDate` if you need it to, but if you don't have a huge database, then you might not want to bother selecting that checkbox.

To convert this time interval into an `NSDate` just use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval];`  where `timeInterval` is what you get from the database.  This can be put in your `NSManagedObject` subclass so that when you get that property, you get an `NSDate` anyway.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. The docs state: NSManagedObject represents date attributes using NSDate objects, and stores times internally as an NSTimeInterval value since the reference date (which has a time zone of GMT).  The reference date = 1 jan 2001, NOT 1 jan 1970

Comment: THen why do they have the function "dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970"?

Also, so you're saying it makes no difference to amount of storage used to use primitive vs not using?

Comment: You should read the Apple docs. I quoted text out of those docs.

Comment: The reference date for NSDateFormatter is 1 jan 1970.  So, `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` is very useful when working with date formatters.  But, you can ask Apple why NSDate and NSDateFormatter have different reference dates.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have mixed entities that uses both scalar and non-scalar property representations such as `int32_t` for integer or boolean properties but `NSDate*` for date properties, you need to manually edit the generated managed object `.h` file.

Therefore I usually start with creating managed object classes by checking the option *Use scalar properties for primitive data types* (as I have more integer and boolean properties than dates). Then I edit the created header file as follows:

**MYEntity.h**

```
@interface MYEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic) int32_t index;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval date;
@end
```

then becomes:

```
@interface MYEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic) int32_t index;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@end
```

If you are of the kind who doesn't like to manually edit this file, you can also choose to add a convenience property using a category that allows for accessing the scalar property as if it would be an object.

**MYEntity+Convenience.h:**

```
@interface MYEntity (Convenience)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSDate *theDate
@end
```

**MYEntity+Convenience.h:**

```
@implementation MYEntity (Convenience)

- (NSDate *)theDate {
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:self.date];
}

- (void)setTheDate:(NSDate *)theDate {
    self.date = [theDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
}

@end
```

To make the code more readable in this example I would name the original property `dateTimeInterval` in the data model designer and the convenience property with its desired name: `date`.

The second approach obviously also works vice versa. You can export your entities with non-scalar properties and then provide a convenience scalar property whose getter and setter accesses the original non-scalar property.