# Changing NSTimeInterval to NSDate

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I checked that I wanted Scalars when creating my `Core Data` objects. I manually changed `NSTimeInterval` to `NSDate`. Is this OK?

Related question: [Why is an NSDate in a Core Data managed Object converted to NSTimeInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841579/why-is-an-nsdate-in-a-core-data-managed-object-converted-to-nstimeinterval)

Comment: I am sure that this is OK, and it worked in all my tests. However, the official Core Data documentation is quite outdated with respect to scalar accessor methods, therefore I cannot "prove" that by pointing to some reference.