# Default NSTimeInterval used by CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate, nstimeinterval

`NSDate` value is returned by `CloudKit`. Which representation will system choose, when I am storing date in Core Data as `NSTimeInterval`? I know `NSTimeInterval` stores number of seconds since some specific reference date. But which reference date will be choosen here?

`mo.setValue(record.creationDate, forKey: "creationDate")`

Latter on I have to compare this date with current date, so I have to convert it back to `NSDate`, so I have to use one of the `NSDate timeIntervalSinceXXX` methods.

---

I have found this in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html):

> Dates and Times
>   NSManagedObject represents date attributes using NSDate objects, and stores times internally as an NSTimeInterval value since the reference date (which has a time zone of GMT). Time zones are not explicitly stored—indeed you should always represent a Core Data date attribute in GMT, this way searches are normalized in the database. If you need to preserve the time zone information, you need to store a time zone attribute in your model. This may again require you to create a subclass of NSManagedObject.

I does not say anything what is the reference

Comment: i'd guess  `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` Everything else would just cause problems.

Comment: phew, i did not know about that one ;) i will google for a bit...

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841579/why-is-an-nsdate-in-a-core-data-managed-object-converted-to-nstimeinterval ?

Comment: and here you probably have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705062/behind-the-scenes-core-data-dates-stored-with-31-year-offset

Comment: doc is not so 'straightforward', 1970 could be also a 'reference date' but I think  `stores times internally as an NSTimeInterval value since the reference date` sentence means `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` I have to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation and in comments, the internal `NSDate` reference date is  1 January 2001, which is what is used by Core Data internally when serializing `NSDate` objects to the database representation.

See [Wikipedia's article on epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). `NSDate` and `CFDate` both use the Cocoa epoch time (which dates at least to 1994, in [the OpenStep specifications](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/OpenStepSpec.pdf.gz#page=373)).