# dateFromString results wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Am Trying to convert NSString to NSDate and then store it on Core Data. I added the timezone to NSDateFormatter still it returns wrong output. And is stored in different format in Core Data.

```
NSString *dateString=@"2015-09-17 01:06:44";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date_f = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"date string %@",dateString);
NSLog(@"date %@",date_f);


 NSManagedObject *events=[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:app.context];
[events setValue:date_f forKey:@"start_date"];
```

Console Output was

```
date string 2015-09-17 01:06:44
date 2015-09-16 19:36:44 +0000
```

Data is stored in Core Data as below

```
start_date = "September 17, 2015";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your time zone is `UTC+05:30` isn't it? `NSLog` prints the date in UTC.

Comment: yup its UTC+05:30

Comment: `date 2015-09-17 01:06:44 +0000` Now its printing correct ...but while storing it on core data the the format is  `September 17, 2015`

Comment: If the type of the Core Data attribute is `NSDate` the displayed format doesn't matter because `NSDate` is actually just a `Double` value.

Comment: But its not getting saved in required format ... It is not saving the time only the date is save.!!

Comment: How are you printing the value after fetching it from the core data object?

Comment: `NSLog` `2015-09-17 01:06:44 +0000` this is the format after converting into UTC
Is there a solution to get rid of the `+0000`

Comment: `NSLog` prints the `description` of the `NSDate` instance. If you need a specific format, use a date formatter.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` was the format set but still getting the `+0000` at the end

Comment: Again, NSDate is not a string as stated by @vadian. If you want the date in the same initial format you must convert it back to string using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a misunderstanding of time zone conversion. A thing that also gave me some headaches in the past :)

Here is what is done:

- You have a date string
- You tell that this date string is in local time zone
- You convert the string to NSDate
- NSDate is now an UTC date because there is no time zone information in a NSDate object

Now, about Core Data and NSManagedObject, you can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841579/why-is-an-nsdate-in-a-core-data-managed-object-converted-to-nstimeinterval). I don't know how your are currently getting this `start_date` value but first thing is to check you Core Data configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation... The Core data accepts `start_date` in `NSDate` format.

Comment: OK, but how did you print the `start_date` value you are showing here? `NSLog` after reading from Core Data?

Comment: Yup i printed using `NSLog` format was `September 17, 2015`

Comment: Well, it is unexpected to have different `NSLog` result for a same type. Did you check the type of your Core Data entry? Have you tried to format your `start_date` to string to see all its components?